# Как в андроид создать меню внутри фигуры (например, восьмиугольника). И каждый пункт меню разместить в отдельном кликабельном секторе?

Tags: android, menu, shape, рисование

Хочу создать контекстное меню в виде восьмиугольника, и каждый пункт меню в отдельном секторе.

Меню создать не проблема. Но вот не знаю как отобразить это меню в виде восьмигранника с секторами, и чтобы каждый сектор был кликабельным.

Нашел в одной программе такое меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно запихнуть меню в какую либо фигуру, разбитую на сектора? Может, есть библиотека или пример, можно даже в виде других фигур.

Comment: Пишите свой View наследник.

Comment: @Style-7,  у Вас есть какие то пример или ссылки как его писать ?

Comment: примеров просто неприличное количество. https://www.raywenderlich.com/142-android-custom-view-tutorial